# Policy based design in Python

Tags: python, policy-based-design

I was very impressed by the policy based design described in `Modern C++ Design` by Andrei Alexandrescu and tried it successfully in some light weight programs. Now I have to write a real world system in `Python` and I think that approach would be very useful here. However, I can't find a single example of this approach in `Python`. Is it not recommended in `Python` or are there better alternatives? Can someone point me to an example of policy based design in `Python`? My aim is to develop an auctioning system and I want to be able to choose the auction strategy - `English`, `Dutch`, `Silent`, etc - at run time.

Since `Python` and `Ruby` are so similar, I guess an example in `Ruby` will also do.

Comment: What's the question here? It might also help if you provide information about, or links to information about, "policy based design".

Comment: @Marcin I have already asked if policy-based design is recommended in Python or if there are better alternatives? I have now added another one - "point me to an example of policy based design in Python". And I have specified that I am talking about the "policy based design" as described in "Modern C++ Design". Which part would you like me to elaborate on?

Comment: You should maybe continue reading my comment past its first sentence. Just because something has the linguistic structure of a question, it does not follow that it actually represents a sensible question.

Comment: I suspect that most users on this site don't own the book "Modern C++ Design", so you're not likely to get an answer unless you can describe it well enough to people that haven't read it before.

Comment: If your question is whether it's recommended, it's off-topic because it's primarily opinion-based. If you want to be pointed to examples, it's off-topic because it's asking about off-site resources. See [Help Center: On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> My aim is to develop an auctioning system and I want to be able to choose the auction strategy - English, Dutch, Silent, etc - at run time.

You could just use [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (also known as the policy pattern) to accomplish exactly this.

You could also use [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) to provide the strategy instead of composition.